# $x_1 ,x_2, ... , x_9$ are the roots of $x^9+7x-2$; then $(x_1)^9+(x_2)^9+ ...+(x_9)^9=?$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $x_1 ,x_2, ... , x_9$ are the roots of $x^9+7x-2$ then 
$(x_1)^9+(x_2)^9+ ...+(x_9)^9=?$

I have not figure it out yet, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Hint:* Since $x_i^9 = -7x_i+2$, you just need to find the sum of the roots.

Comment: i thought like that then what will be the summation of the $x_i$

Comment: @AlperErdem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas.

Answer (score 6):

Taking $x_1$ as an example

$$
(x_1)^9 = -7x_1+2
$$

so in general
$$
(x_i)^9 = -7x_i+2
$$

So in the end you get:

$$
x_1^9 + ...+x_9^9 = -7(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_9)+18
$$

Can you proceed from here? What do you know about the sum of the roots of a polynomial?

Answer (score -3):

I plugged this polynomial into MATLAB using

```
P = roots[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, -2]
```

and got

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|r}
  -1.2104 + 0.4893i  \\
  -1.2104 - 0.4893i  \\
  -0.5216 + 1.1818i  \\
  -0.5216 - 1.1818i  \\
   0.4514 + 1.1829i  \\
   0.4514 - 1.1829i  \\
   1.1378 + 0.4906i  \\
   1.1378 - 0.4906i  \\
   0.2857 + 0.0000i  \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Taking each term to the 9th power,

```
X = P.^9
```

you get

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|r}
  10.4726 - 3.4253i  \\
  10.4726 + 3.4253i  \\
   5.6514 - 8.2728i  \\
   5.6514 + 8.2728i  \\
  -1.1597 - 8.2805i  \\
  -1.1597 + 8.2805i  \\
  -5.9643 - 3.4343i  \\
  -5.9643 + 3.4343i  \\
   0                 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

The sum of all these terms is $$18$$

Comment: And without a computer, how would you have done it?

Comment: Nope...I'm too stupid.